# Replace a list of numbers with flat sub-ranges

Tags: python, list, numpy

Given a list of numbers, like this:

```
lst = [0, 10, 15, 17]
```

I'd like a list that has elements from `i -> i + 3` for all `i` in `lst`. If there are overlapping ranges, I'd like them merged.

So, for the example above, we first get:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3,     10, 11, 12, 13,     15, 16, 17, 18,   17, 18, 19, 20]
```

But for the last 2 groups, the ranges overlap, so upon merging them, you have:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3,     10, 11, 12, 13,     15, 16, 17, 18,     19, 20]
```

This is my desired output.

This is what I've thought of:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

res = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([y for x in lst for y in range(x, x + 4)]).keys())
print(res) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

However, this is slow (`10000 loops, best of 3: 56 µs per loop`). I'd like a numpy solution if possible, or a python solution that's faster than this.

Comment: are the original elements guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes. Guaranteed.

Comment: @Coldspeed then you can use that. Casting to `set` and then `sort`ing again if it makes it any faster.

Comment: @ChristianDean Oh sorry, I was running this on python2.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ah, my mistake then. I didn't realize there was a difference between versions. I rarely use Python 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** One approach based on [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) summation and then using `np.unique` to get unique numbers -

```
np.unique(np.asarray(lst)[:,None] + np.arange(4))
```

**Approach #2 :** Another based on broadcasted summation and then masking -

```
def mask_app(lst, interval_len = 4):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    r = np.arange(interval_len)
    ranged_vals = arr[:,None] + r
    a_diff = arr[1:] - arr[:-1]
    valid_mask = np.vstack((a_diff[:,None] > r, np.ones(interval_len,dtype=bool)))
    return ranged_vals[valid_mask]
```

**Runtime test**

Original approach -

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def org_app(lst):
    list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([y for x in lst for y in range(x, x + 4)]).keys())
```

Timings -

```
In [409]: n = 10000

In [410]: lst = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,4*n,(n))).tolist()

In [411]: %timeit org_app(lst)
     ...: %timeit np.unique(np.asarray(lst)[:,None] + np.arange(4))
     ...: %timeit mask_app(lst, interval_len = 4)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 32.7 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 671 µs per loop

In [412]: n = 100000

In [413]: lst = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,4*n,(n))).tolist()

In [414]: %timeit org_app(lst)
     ...: %timeit np.unique(np.asarray(lst)[:,None] + np.arange(4))
     ...: %timeit mask_app(lst, interval_len = 4)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 350 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.73 ms per loop
```

The bottleneck with the two posted approaches seems like is with the conversion to `array`, though that seems to be paying off well afterwards. Just to give a sense of the time spent on the conversion for the last dataset -

```
In [415]: %timeit np.array(lst)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Beautiful. Works like a charm and blazing fast too.